# Discord.js how to add roles

Tags: discord.js

Now I believe this is a bit of an older version of discord.js but I'm not sure. I'm attempting to add a "Muted" role when you say a certain word, which in this case is "Heck". In the console I'm getting and error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined" and I'm not sure what to do here. Here is my code:

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if(message.content.includes('Heck')) {
        message.reply('Not allowed');
        let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");
        console.log('works')
        let member = message.mentions.members.first();
        console.log('works')
        member.roles.add(role)
        console.log('works')
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bot can't find `Muted` role in guild or there is no member mention to add role

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if(message.content.includes('Heck')) {
        message.reply('Not allowed');
        let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");
        if (!role) return console.log("no role found");
        console.log('works')
        let member = message.mentions.members.first();
        if (!member) return console.log("no member mentioned");
        console.log('works')
        member.roles.add(role)
        console.log('works')
    }
});
```

This will log `no role found` if `Muted` role not found in guild and if role exists & no member mention then it will log `no member mentioned` in console

Comment: Nothing came back, so I'm not sure what's wrong here. Though the error is now "TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined". I can send my full code.

Comment: then i guess its member problem - https://hatebin.com/dhihacunvr

Comment: You are correct, how would I add the role then?

Comment: you have to mention a member first to add role
Ex
[prefix]Heck @emoji

Comment: Is there any other way? I'm trying to mute somebody if they say "Heck" as I don't think someone would say "-Heck @emoji".

Comment: you mean you want to mute someone if they say heck? if yes then please just use message.member.roles.add(ID);

Comment: Right, my code is now:

client.on('message', (message) => {
    if(message.content.includes('Heck')) {
        message.reply('Not allowed');
        console.log('works')
        message.member.roles.add(804735741225730078);
        console.log('works')
    }
});

It logs it but I wasn't given the role. It gave an error "(node:11116) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not an Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes."

Comment: Ok, I forgot to add the "" in the ID. Thanks for your help!

Comment: no problem, thanks for accepting as answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without having a mute role

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    if(message.content.includes('Heck')) {
        let member = message.member;
        for (var [snowflake, channel] of msg.guild.channels.cache) {
            channel.overwritePermissions(member, { SEND_MESSAGES: false })
                .then()
                .catch(console.error);
        }
    }
}
```